# Race condition reading stdout and stderr of child process

Tags: go, timeout, race-condition, child-process, goroutine

In Go, I'm trying to:

1. start a subprocess
2. read from stdout and stderr separately
3. implement an overall timeout

After much googling, we've come up with some code that seems to do the job, most of the time. But there seems to be a race condition whereby some output is not read.

The problem seems to only occur on Linux, not Windows.

Following the simplest possible solution found with google, we tried creating a context with a timeout:

```golang
context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
```

While this worked most of the time, we were able to find cases where it would just hang forever. There was some aspect of the child process that caused this to deadlock. (Something to do with grandchildren that were not sufficiently dissasociated from the child process, and thus caused the child to never completely exit.)

Also, it seemed that in some cases the `error` that is returned when the timeout occurrs would indicate a timeout, but would only be delivered **after** the process had actually exited (thus making the whole concept of the timeout useless).

```golang
func GetOutputsWithTimeout(command string, args []string, timeout int) (io.ReadCloser, io.ReadCloser, int, error) {
    start := time.Now()
    procLogger.Tracef("Initializing %s %+v", command, args)
    cmd := exec.Command(command, args...)

    // get pipes to standard output/error
    stdout, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil {
        return emptyReader(), emptyReader(), -1, fmt.Errorf("cmd.StdoutPipe() error: %+v", err.Error())
    }
    stderr, err := cmd.StderrPipe()
    if err != nil {
        return emptyReader(), emptyReader(), -1, fmt.Errorf("cmd.StderrPipe() error: %+v", err.Error())
    }

    // setup buffers to capture standard output and standard error
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    var ebuf bytes.Buffer

    // create a channel to capture any errors from wait
    done := make(chan error)
    // create a semaphore to indicate when both pipes are closed
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(2)

    go func() {
        if _, err := buf.ReadFrom(stdout); err != nil {
            procLogger.Debugf("%s: Error Slurping stdout: %+v", command, err)
        }
        wg.Done()
    }()
    go func() {
        if _, err := ebuf.ReadFrom(stderr); err != nil {
            procLogger.Debugf("%s: Error  Slurping stderr: %+v", command, err)
        }
        wg.Done()
    }()

    // start process
    procLogger.Debugf("Starting %s", command)
    if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
        procLogger.Errorf("%s: failed to start: %+v", command, err)
        return emptyReader(), emptyReader(), -1, fmt.Errorf("cmd.Start() error: %+v", err.Error())
    }

    go func() {
        procLogger.Debugf("Waiting for %s (%d) to finish", command, cmd.Process.Pid)
        err := cmd.Wait()                                             // this can  be 'forced' by the killing of the process
        procLogger.Tracef("%s finished: errStatus=%+v", command, err) // err could be nil here
        //notify select of completion, and the status
        done <- err
    }()

    // Wait for timeout or completion.
    select {
    // Timed out
    case <-time.After(time.Duration(timeout) * time.Second):
        elapsed := time.Since(start)
        procLogger.Errorf("%s: timeout after %.1f\n", command, elapsed.Seconds())
        if err := TerminateTree(cmd); err != nil {
            return ioutil.NopCloser(&buf), ioutil.NopCloser(&ebuf), -1,
                fmt.Errorf("failed to kill %s, pid=%d: %+v",
                    command, cmd.Process.Pid, err)
        }
        wg.Wait() // this *should* take care of waiting for stdout and stderr to be collected after we killed the process
        return ioutil.NopCloser(&buf), ioutil.NopCloser(&ebuf), -1,
            fmt.Errorf("%s: timeout %d s reached, pid=%d process killed",
                command, timeout, cmd.Process.Pid)
    //Exited normally or with a non-zero exit code
    case err := <-done:
        wg.Wait() // this *should* take care of waiting for stdout and stderr to be collected after the process terminated naturally.
        elapsed := time.Since(start)
        procLogger.Tracef("%s: Done after %.1f\n", command, elapsed.Seconds())
        rc := -1
        // Note that we have to use go1.10 compatible mechanism.
        if err != nil {
            procLogger.Tracef("%s exited with error: %+v", command, err)
            exitErr, ok := err.(*exec.ExitError)
            if ok {
                ws := exitErr.Sys().(syscall.WaitStatus)
                rc = ws.ExitStatus()
            }
            procLogger.Debugf("%s exited with status %d", command, rc)
            return ioutil.NopCloser(&buf), ioutil.NopCloser(&ebuf), rc,
                fmt.Errorf("%s: process done with error: %+v",
                    command, err)
        } else {
            ws := cmd.ProcessState.Sys().(syscall.WaitStatus)
            rc = ws.ExitStatus()
        }
        procLogger.Debugf("%s exited with status %d", command, rc)
        return ioutil.NopCloser(&buf), ioutil.NopCloser(&ebuf), rc, nil
    }
    //NOTREACHED: should not reach this line!
}
```

Calling `GetOutputsWithTimeout("uname",[]string{"-mpi"},10)` will return the expected single line of output *most of the time*. But sometimes it will return *no output*, as if the goroutine that reads stdout didn't start soon enough to "catch" all the output (or exited early?) The "most of the time" strongly suggests a race condition.

We will also sometimes see errors from the goroutines about "file already closed" (this seems to happen with the timeout condition, but will happen at other "normal" times as well).

I would have thought that starting the goroutines before the `cmd.Start()` would have ensured that no output would be missed, and that using the `WaitGroup` would guarantee they would both complete before reading the buffers.

So how are we missing output? Is there still a race condition between the two "reader" goroutines and the `cmd.Start()`? Should we ensure those two are running using yet another `WaitGroup`?

Or is there a problem with the implementation of `ReadFrom()`?

Note that we are currently using go1.10 due to backward-compatibility problems with older OSs but the same effect occurs with go1.12.4.

Or are we overthinking this, and a simple implementation with `context.WithTimeout()` would do the job?

Comment: Run the application with the [race detector](https://golang.org/doc/articles/race_detector.html) in case it points to any problems.

Answer (score 0):

> But sometimes it will return no output, as if the goroutine that reads stdout didn't start soon enough to "catch" all the output

This is impossible, because a pipe can't "lose" data. If the process is writing to stdout and the Go program isn't reading yet, the process will block.

The simplest way to approach the problem is:

- Launch goroutines to collect stdout, stderr
- Launch a timer that kills the process
- Start the process
- Wait for it to finish (or be killed by the timer) with .Wait()
- If timer is fired, return timeout error
- Handle wait error

```golang
func GetOutputsWithTimeout(command string, args []string, timeout int) ([]byte, []byte, int, error) {
    cmd := exec.Command(command, args...)

    // get pipes to standard output/error
    stdout, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, nil, -1, fmt.Errorf("cmd.StdoutPipe() error: %+v", err.Error())
    }
    stderr, err := cmd.StderrPipe()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, nil, -1, fmt.Errorf("cmd.StderrPipe() error: %+v", err.Error())
    }

    // setup buffers to capture standard output and standard error
    var stdoutBuf, stderrBuf []byte

    // create 3 goroutines: stdout, stderr, timer.
    // Use a waitgroup to wait.
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(2)

    go func() {
        var err error
        if stdoutBuf, err = ioutil.ReadAll(stdout); err != nil {
            log.Printf("%s: Error Slurping stdout: %+v", command, err)
        }
        wg.Done()
    }()
    go func() {
        var err error
        if stderrBuf, err = ioutil.ReadAll(stderr); err != nil {
            log.Printf("%s: Error Slurping stderr: %+v", command, err)
        }
        wg.Done()
    }()

    t := time.AfterFunc(time.Duration(timeout)*time.Second, func() {
        cmd.Process.Kill()
    })

    // start process
    if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
        t.Stop()
        return nil, nil, -1, fmt.Errorf("cmd.Start() error: %+v", err.Error())
    }

    err = cmd.Wait()
    timedOut := !t.Stop()
    wg.Wait()

    // check if the timer timed out.
    if timedOut {
        return stdoutBuf, stderrBuf, -1,
            fmt.Errorf("%s: timeout %d s reached, pid=%d process killed",
                command, timeout, cmd.Process.Pid)
    }

    if err != nil {
        rc := -1
        if exitErr, ok := err.(*exec.ExitError); ok {
            rc = exitErr.Sys().(syscall.WaitStatus).ExitStatus()
        }
        return stdoutBuf, stderrBuf, rc,
            fmt.Errorf("%s: process done with error: %+v",
                command, err)
    }

    // cmd.Wait docs say that if err == nil, exit code is 0
    return stdoutBuf, stderrBuf, 0, nil
}
```